# Possessive punctuation missing from "What are the different types of users in a Collective?" page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, collectives, grammatical-correction

When viewing the [What are the different types of users in a Collective?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/collectives-user-types) page the section describing the Admin role has a missing possessive apostrophe:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As much as I appreciate grammatical nitpicks, this one is a miss. That doesn't need a possessive apostrophe.

"Collectives" is a product name, so there's nothing wrong with the phrasing or grammar of that sentence.

The name "Collectives" happens to be plural, so perhaps that's confusing. Replace this name with a singular and re-test the sentence:

> These admins have full access to all the Stack Overflow features…

As that substitution hopefully makes clear, "Stack Overflow" isn't possessive, and it doesn't need an apostrophe. The same holds true for "Collectives" in the original sentence.

Comment: I agree with this answer, although I personally would prefer that the leading "the" be removed (and the remainder of the sentence adjusted appropriately): *"These admins have full access to all Collectives features, including those which are described under Recognized Members"*.

Comment: Or, alternatively, @Nick, add "of" preceding "the".

Comment: Indeed!, but not replacing the preceding "the" with "of", as then it would require being in a possessive form.